# How do I combine two words into one string?

Tags: r, syntax, analysis, stringr

I have a little syntax problem, I am trying to perform sentiment analysis based on **positive words**, **negative words** and **negative-positive words** (e.g.="not able"), basically 3 dictionaries.

For positive and negative dictionaries the world classificiation is pretty easy I just use:

`scan('positive.txt', what='character', comment.char=";")`

and the results is pretty much all the single positive words however when it comes to negative-positive words it gets tricky, when I use

`scan('negative-positive.txt', what='character', comment.char=";")`

the result is the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Fz9.png)

How can I make "not + adjective" as a single word not a divided one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine two strings/characters in R, you can use this:

```
combined_word<-paste0("positive","negative")
print(combined_word)
```

Output

```
[1] "positivenegative"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the results using `paste` along the lines of what ashwin agrawal demonstrated. However, this solution will only work if all of your positive-negative phrases contain exactly two words (or the same number of words, actually).

It is typically better to eliminate problems at the root – i.e. read the data correctly, in the first place. I am not sure what your files look like, but I assume that you have one phrase per line. In that case, you may want to set the `sep` parameter to indicate what separates the phrases (newline in that case):

```
scan("foo.txt", what="character", sep="\n", comment.char=";")
```